# Something strange with blank fields in symfony2 forms

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

when i send a form with a blank field i get an error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image' cannot be null`. the only way to fix it that i found is to make a default value in the entity file:

```
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $image="";
```

and change the setter like this:

```
public function setImage($image){
 if(!isset($image)) {
//its really empty but it works only in this way     
}
     else {
    $this->image = $image;
    }
```

I think that it is very starnge...
Is there any explanation for this? And is there another way to do it?
    }

Comment: Does property `image` is required or not? If not, you can have this definition instead `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)`.

Comment: It's not required. I made your suggestion, and updated the schema and really it works. Thank you!

Comment: I'm gonna make it an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the field `image` is not required, you can set it as `nullable` so Doctrine will know that and will set the column as being nullable.

This way, constraint won't be violated since the field can be null. To make a field nullable with Doctrine annotation, just add `nullable = true` in the `ORM\Column` definition like this:

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
```

By default, all columns are `nullable=false` so they will throw a constaint validation exception when trying to persist a null value in it.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: But why is an empty textfield `null` and not `""` (=empty string)?

Comment: Don't know, never dug on this point. Maybe a design decision of Symfony2. They may be a possibility to customize that at the form level by providing an option ...

Comment: See my answer for "why"

Answer (score 2):

The why is partially answered here:

[Symfony2 forms interpret blank strings as nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928702/symfony2-forms-interpret-blank-strings-as-nulls)

This code gets around it because when Symfony sets `$image` to null and calls `$entity->setImage(null)`, this code will not change the `$image` member.

```
public function setImage($image){
    if(!isset($image)) {
        // $image is null, symfony was trying to set $this->image to null, prevent it
    } else {
        $this->image = $image;
    }
}
```

This is more explicit (and who wants that weird empty statement anyway?). It expresses your intent, that `$this->image` cannot be null (which matches the database definition if you don't make it nullable)

```
public function setImage($image){
    if(isset($image)) {
        // $image not null, go ahead and use it
        $this->image = $image;
    }
}
```

Either way, you need to initialize `$this->image` otherwise it will default to `null`.

Comment: Funny, double Matt answers :)