# A space in SQL result in a performance gap of 100 times, why?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to use `pymysql.executemany` to multi insert.

But the less of a space after `VALUES` in sql causes the running time to increase. Why is that?

Here is my code, check the two `run` function.

```
import pymysql.cursors

from functools import wraps
from datetime import datetime


def running_time(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def deco():
        t0 = datetime.now()
        res = func()
        t1 = datetime.now()
        print(t1 - t0)
        return res
    return deco


CONFIG = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 3306,
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '',
    'db': 'test',
    'charset': 'utf8',
    'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
    'autocommit': True,
}
connection = pymysql.connect(**CONFIG)
cur = connection.cursor()


@running_time
def run():
    sql = """INSERT INTO table_name(c) VALUES (%s)"""
    for i in range(100):
        param = ['1'] * 2000
        cur.executemany(sql, param)
run()


@running_time
def run():
    sql = """INSERT INTO table_name(c) VALUES(%s)"""
    for i in range(100):
        param = ['1'] * 2000
        cur.executemany(sql, param)
run()
```

outputs:

> 0:00:02.765183
>
> 0:01:13.729428

Comment: A similar question was posted before. Refer to this topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017239/how-do-null-values-affect-performance-in-a-database-search)

Comment: I think this is not the same problem. I am confused the syntax of sql, not the value of data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of `pymysql`.

Check this: [allow no whitespaces between `VALUES` and `(` when do bulk insert/replace #597](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/pull/597)